# How to change background an extended JButton in java when mouse over

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

I am using my class call KButton that extends from JButton bui I add some code that make it more beautiful such as changing the font, set rounded border, change the background using Graphics and Graphics2D. However it is not work when i want to add code to make it change color when move over! my code is here

```
public class KButton extends JButton implements MouseMotionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public KButton(){
        setStyle();
    }
    public KButton(String text){        
        super(text);
        this.setText(text);
        setStyle();
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    public void setStyle(){
        setFont(new Font("San Serif",Font.PLAIN,12));
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorder(new RoundedBorder(3));
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), Color.WHITE, new Point(0, getHeight()), Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Graphics g=this.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), Color.WHITE, new Point(0, getHeight()), Color.BLUE.brighter()));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
        super.setText(getText());
        setBorder(new RoundedBorder(3));
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

and it seems not work!

Comment: You might look into using a custom PLAF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @MadProgrammer's advice is true, you can omit all this burden by setting the buttons rollover image:

```
//In constructor
setRolloverImage(myRolloverImage);
```

But I'm not sure this is the exact method name, do some research.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getGraphics`. The approriate place to perform custom painting is within the `paintComponent` method.  `getGraphics` is a transient reference to the graphics context last used to the paint the component, when the component is repainted, any changes will be overridden by those in the various `paintXxx` methods.

You should, also, never be calling any of the `paintXxx` methods yourself (unless you are trying to render the component to an image of course)

Instead, use a state flag to changes the way that `paintComponent` works and call `repaint` when you want to update the state.

In your case, there are at least two things that destroying your painting efforts in your `mouseMoved` method, `setText` and the mouse movement itself. Both of which will cause a `repaint` to occur.

Personally, I would use `MouseListener#mouseEntered` and `MouseListener#mouseExited` instead and change the state of the button model (to rolled over for example) and then examine that value in the `paintComponent` method to make my painting decisions

Also, beware that `super.paintComponent` will attempt to clear the graphics context, preparing for painting and should be called first

Answer (score 0):

Don't do painting in `mouseMoved`, just set the properties to paint, and then repaint the component . Also, MouseListener provides mouseEntered and mouseExited events, which work better for this use case. :

```
public class KButton extends JButton {
  private Color bottomBg = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

  public KButton(String text) {
    super(text);
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), Color.WHITE, new Point(0, getHeight()), this.bottomBg));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
    this.bottomBg = Color.BLUE.brighter();
    this.repaint();
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
    this.bottomBg = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    this.repaint();
  }

  // add other MouseListener methods, or use a MouseAdapter 
  // with just those two methods overridden

}
```